# Asus V1S screen dimming randomly

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, laptop-repair, asus-laptop

I have an Asus V1V, which is the same as the Asus V1S except for the video card.

I have a problem where the screen will randomly lose brightness or flicker between being lit and not lit.

The picture below is of the left hinge, with the cover removed. Pressing one of these cables affects this behaviour, and pressing it in place will resolve the issue for a few hours.

My guess means the inverter cable is damaged, based on previous experience.

As the picture shows, there are two cables, an LCD cable and what I assume is an inverter cable.

I purchased an LCD cable for my model of laptop, but have been unable to find an inverter cable. It seems not to exist.

I would like some input on if an inverter cable actually exists, if it is likely the problem, or solutions in general to resolve this problem permanently.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If pressing the cable solves the problem for a few hours, this means that the copper core of the cable has broken due to flexing, and pressing it in the right way brings the two broken ends in contact again. Then over time random vibrations will disconnect them again.

A LCD cable problem would likely destroy the signaling to the screen, which would exhibit colored banding, missing/altered colors or other disruption *while remaining lit*.

If you can access and replace the cable along its whole length, then do so, using any cable with the correct number of conductors with the same core diameter (or more). You may be able to reuse the existing connectors, otherwise you'll have to scavenge them from somewhere; but they are usually pretty standard.

Otherwise, if the cable has sufficient slack, you can cut it open at the hinge, splice together and solder back the broken ends, and seal them with thermo-stretch tubing (one piece for each conductor, one more around everything else). You can find the material (and maybe someone who is familiar with soldering irons too, if you need it) in any electronics shop. This second method is trickier, because the enlarged cable must still fit inside, and also will have to withstand being repeatedly flexed in the hinge, so you need extra care.

If you have partial access, you might be able to pull out the cable from the hinge, and splice it at *both* ends, so that it is the "new" section of spliced cable that runs inside the hinge. This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8btWJrW25OU) maybe explains it better.

Needless to say, do this with power and battery disconnected :-)

Comment: Wow, great answer, thank you! I lack the knowledge to solder or repair the actual cable...and am wary of being ripped off price wise trying to find someone to do that. I was hoping just to replace the cable itself, however that part doesn't seem to exist. I've only seen LCD cables and inverter boards (that do not seem to come with a cable).

Comment: Is an inverter cable perhaps more standard and not specific to a model of laptop?

Comment: Possibly, yes. I looked at some "undo your laptop" videos and it always looked an ordinary white and red cable. I believe it's 12V and, a laptop screen surely not getting more than 36-48W at its utter utmost, 3-4A tops. *Maybe* same cable used in motherboards to connect LEDs. Take care **not** to get the single-core (one fat copper wire) one ("telecom" wire), as it doesn't like getting repeatedly flexed. The one made by several thin wires is good. The connectors are more difficult: look for 'male fan connector'.